# build jdk.jdeps with external library

Tags: java, makefile

I'm patching `jdeps` and using an external JAR

1. where and how do I add my JAR to use it inside **jdeps** ?  [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d6961045353897967bb734740225bd1cddf158e5/make/modules/jdk.jdeps/Gensrc.gmk#L37) ?
2. I there a way to only build [jdeps](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jdeps) ?

Notes:

- JDK [Makefile](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/Makefile)
- [jdeps make folder](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/make/modules/jdk.jdeps)
- [SetupCompileProperties](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d6961045353897967bb734740225bd1cddf158e5/make/common/modules/GensrcProperties.gmk#L61)
- **jdeps** compiled to binary and use `libjli.so` to launch JVM

Comment: What do you mean with “jdeps with BCEL library”? There is no relationship between these two things.

Comment: jdeps has its own bytecode processing classes and to extend it, you have to understand them anyway. Adding BCEL is just redundant.

Comment: You’re using a recent JDK, aren’t you? So, everything needed for formatting, is already built-in. See [this example](https://tio.run/##VY69DgIhEIT7e4rNVVC4PsDFzkajlVZaIeDJyQGB9ZKLuWdH1MSfapOZ2W@mE4OYdeqas@mDjwRdEdAK16L0LpFwhFtNF6/2Y9BLnWRTVdKKlGCvE8G9Agi3kzUSSpjKGbxR0Avj2I6iKRxEELHlryjAWwRVSNEE8hEWULP15tk7f/bO34nmeFzxQ13aXl9jIt2jvxGG4pJ17H8V@vPyg2RfOkdlUrBi/HE5bwp0qqacHw)…

Comment: @Holger in your example the output is `(long,String,int[][])boolean` can it have the full path to class ? desired output `(long,java.lang.String,int[][])boolean`.  You deserve points for the comment above, if you create an answer I'll upvote.

Comment: [This, for example](https://tio.run/##hVHLTsMwELz3K1YRB5uHuTdCCPGQQIULPVFxMLZbXOJH7W2lCvHtZR0HyA0piaPx7szs7Fru5NlafxwO1sWQENYEiE76lVDBZ5QexXE7GV9u0XYiYzLSlauJ6mTOMDcZ4XMCELdvnVVArUjHLlgNTlrPnjFZYhUCZFrxvhSggqBNVslGDAkuoGEPsyJ0Xlyc14p2sbhfjND5O8nro2cSMe3sLoSWvzTkpXDuZAKHN0RJZI8G34Oe76MpgAjLm18p9qfK2@pmn9E4EbYoIqli51klEtrm2Mn9qJn/2xNlks6gSTObkfEhMvpxMrIS13S64T0HAIXddUYhu65nSFmsg/U0OmtOgZ7ND20yuE2@TEQe4AQacP2MTyTW1/KGV3Nf9A5rGHLesOuyrD4b9bMDu2RK2HyVktwXyipAtYpc0d698TiSW7w27Xh3kVIuw6oPuTK9CX4KugeH1CpYmwbySIK3LiIJXoKeEgkxi4a@ujr/Ohy@AQ) but it’s not an answer to the question you asked.